# Error when opening Office documents from library through native client

Tags: error, sharepoint-on-prem

We have a strange error on a Sharepoint 2013 farm since a few days. Opening documents using any native Office 2016 client (e.g. Word) does not work anymore. It shows the error below and they do not open at all. The documents can be opened in Web App mode however.

"There are network issues stopping us from opening your document. Please try again later."

[image]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Enable and start **Network List Service** on the client computer. To do this, follow these steps:

- Click Start, type "**services.msc**" (without quotation marks) in the Start Search box and press Enter.
- Double-click **Network List Service**.
- Right-click the service, and then click **Start**.

Microsoft reference documentation:

[Office files in SharePoint fail to open from an Office 2016 client](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-for-mac/files-fail-to-open)

Comment: Thanks, I found that link already. But the issue happens on all computers and that service is running (tried to restart it also). I think the error message is totally misleading and the cause is on the server side

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some services were having issues server side. A reboot of the farm solved the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/109231)

Comment: @AmitKotha Sorry about this. I intended to not leave a question open. We did not find a proper cause and a reboot solved the issue. Should I delete the entire question ? Or just mark my own answer above as the solution ?